# My flag button doesn't work properly

Tags: support, flagging

Recently I tried to flag [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23828/how-to-add-hardware-to-arduino-ide-on-raspberry-pi) to be  migrated by clicking flag then the "should be closed" option then "off-topic because..." and then "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"
but then the only option it gave was to migrate to the meta of Raspberry Pi! Why? I do have an account on the Arduino SE so I feel that I should at least be able to move it there (which is where the question is now) but i can't. Why?

Comment: I realize this isn't an exact duplicate of the other question, but if you read the answer there it may help to explain why we do not have migration paths for normal users.  If you think a question should be closed as off-topic, use "close".  If you really want to use a flag to indicate you think something should be migrated in particular, use a custom flag message.    There is no policy on SE that having an account on one site entitles you to flag things for migration to it on another as far as I am aware.

Comment: [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) (i.e., chat) is also a good place to get moderator attention for stuff like this.  *Usually* [one of us](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) has been there recently enough to be pinged directly.

Comment: @goldilocks The question you cite is similar but i do not believe that it applies as i would have migrated to Arduino and he wanted to do to and from the meta.

Comment: It applies in the sense that there aren't any real migration paths; the one to our own meta is essentially internal.  My point there about the evolution of attitudes toward user migration paths on SE generally is that it has been *away* from it because it was/is something that creates more problems than it solves.  I remember being on the other of this debate at U&L 2-3 years ago: "Why can't we vote to migrate to ____?  And _____?".   There would be even less point here.   We have *at most* a few dozen questions a day and maybe a half handful of migrations a week,

Comment: but three fairly diligent mods (our average flag handling time this year so far is 61 minutes).  I migrated that to Arduino as soon as I saw it (which was actually a bit trigger happy, since the OP had already cross posted it).  You can investigate the whole topic further on [SE Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) proper -- these aren't decisions I make, but I think I understand the rationale behind this one.  There's no real problem, and opening up migration options to everyone in the past has only *created*, not solved them.